# Cauchy functional inequality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations, functional-inequalities

Given a function on a closed interval $f\colon I\subset \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ with $$f(x+y) \leq f(x) + f(y).$$ Moreover, I know that $f$ is

- monotonic increasing
- continuous on all points except countably many
- continuous from the right
- such that the limit from the left at each point exists.
- $f(nx) \leq nf(x)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Can I say more on this function? In particular, I would like to show that $f(\lambda x) \leq \lambda f(x)$ for all $\lambda \geq 1$ or at least for all rational $\lambda \geq 1$.

Comment: Maybe you should also require that $f$ is strictly positive. For instance, consider $f(x)=x-2$ on the interval $I=[0,2]$. This function satisfies all of the hypotheses listed, but taking $\lambda =2$ and $x=1$,

$$
0=f(2) = f(2\cdot 1) \nleq 2\cdot f(1) =2(-1)=-2.$$

I am not sure if that suffices to prove the desired statement though.

Comment: Note that your $f$ does not satisfy the subadditivity. Your example shows $f(x+x) \nleq f(x) + f(x) $

Comment: If $f(lx)\leq l f(x)$ for positive rational $l$ then for $x , x/n \in I$ we have $f(x)\leq n f(x/n)\leq n\cdot n^{-1} f(x)=f(x)$, implying $f(x)/n=f(x/n).$

Comment: @user254665, the question is whether this holds for *some* $\lambda \ge 1$; you try to apply this for *any* $\lambda>0$, even for $\lambda<1$.

Comment: @zhoraster. The Q says "for all" as of May 7, 11:00 EDT

Comment: @user254665, you are right. Anyway, $\lambda\ge 1$. You are trying to apply this to $\lambda = 1/n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this inequality is guaranteed *exclusively* for integer $\lambda$.

Take e.g. $f(x) = x + |\sin x|$. Then $$
f(x + y) = x+ y + |\sin x\cos y + \sin y \cos x|\\\le x+ y + |\sin x\cos y| + |\sin y \cos x|\\
\le x+ y + |\sin x| + |\sin y| = f(x) + f(y).$$

It also satisfies all other assumptions (note that the last one follows from the Cauchy functional inequality).

Then for any $\lambda>1$, $f(\lambda \pi) - \lambda f(\pi) = |\sin\lambda \pi| - \lambda |\sin \pi| = |\sin\lambda \pi|$ is positive unless $\lambda\in \mathbb Z$.